# How to 'reply done' in Gerrit when I address people code review comment

Tags: gerrit

When using Gerrit review, I want to 'reply done'.
So I click 'Reply Done' button. But it is in 'draft' state? How can I submit the 'Reply done'?

Answer (score 7):

After you have added your comments to the files you will need to either go and do a 'Review' or 'Add Comment'. This will then also publish your draft comments.

Answer (score 5):

In the change overview, there is a button "Reply.." (on top, right of the commit message).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add your reply to the comment by clicking on the comment, then click on reply button and post your reply.
After you have done with the reply go to the previous page and click on reply button. See StephenKing answer for better clarity.